# VBA Code to add multiple series to a scatter graph - run time 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am writing a code to add multiple series to a line graph. I have also put in a counter to make two separate graphs when a minimum value corresponding to a row is met. My VBA skills are very basic and I get a run time 1004 error at the asterisked line:

```
Dim xrng As Range
Dim yrng As Range
Dim x2rng As Range
Dim y2rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim l As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer

Worksheets("Template").Activate
Dim lv As String
 lv = Worksheets("Template").Range(Worksheets("Template").Range("B11"), Worksheets("Template").Range("B11").End(xlDown)).Find(WorksheetFunction.Small(Worksheets("Template").Range(Worksheets("Template").Range("B11"), Worksheets("Template").Range("B11").End(xlDown)), 1), , , 1).Address
 Range(lv).Select
l = ActiveCell.Row
k = Worksheets("Template").Range(Worksheets("Template").Range("B11"), Worksheets("Template").Range("B11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
i = 1
i2 = 1
Set xrng = Worksheets("Template").Range("C11:CP11")
Set yrng = Worksheets("Template").Range("C201:CP201")
Set x2rng = xrng.Offset(1, 0)
Set y2rng = xrng.Offset(1, 0)
Dim Chart1 As Chart
 Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
With Chart1
 Chart1.ChartType = xlXYScatter
 Chart1.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
 Chart1.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xrng
 Chart1.SeriesCollection(1).Values = yrng
End With
i = i + 1
ITERATE:
If i < l Then
With Chart1
Chart1.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Chart1.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = x2rng
' pretend the next line is bold
Chart1.SeriesCollection(i).Values = y2rng
x2rng = x2rng.Offset(1, 0)
y2rng = y2rng.Offset(1, 0)
i = i + 1
GoTo ITERATE
End With
End If

If i < k Then
Dim Chart2 As Chart
 Set Chart2 = Charts.Add
With Chart2
 Chart2.ChartType = xlXYScatter
 Chart2.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
 Chart2.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = x2rng
 Chart2.SeriesCollection(1).Values = y2rng
End With
End If
i2 = i2 + 1
ITERATE2:
If i < k Then
Chart1.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Chart1.SeriesCollection(i2).XValues = x2rng
Chart1.SeriesCollection(i2).Values = y2rng
x2rng = x2rng.Offset(1, 0)
y2rng = y2rng.Offset(1, 0)
i2 = i2 + 1
GoTo ITERATE2
End If
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Judoo

Comment: where is asterisked line? can you copy that line to a separate line.

Comment: Hello, the asterisked line is: `Chart1.SeriesCollection(i).Values = y2rng` 4 lines after ITERATE